# Display image from API call. How? Why?

Tags: javascript, image, fetch-api

I am trying to display info from an API call, but I don't get the image to display. The weird thing is that they do here, but not in my browser through live server from VScode. Does anyone understand what I'm doing wrong?

```js
const url = "https://api.spacexdata.com/v4/crew";
const resultsContainer = document.querySelector(".crew_box");

async function fetchInfo() {
  try {
    const response = await fetch(url);
    const results = await response.json();

    console.log(results);

    results.forEach(function (crew) {
      resultsContainer.innerHTML += `
                                 <div class="crew_box"><img src="${crew.image}"                                      
                                 <h6>${crew.name}</h6>
                                 <h6>${crew.agency}</h6>
                                 </div>`;
    });
  } catch (error) {
    console.log(error);
    resultsContainer.innerHTML = message("error", error);
  }
}

fetchInfo();
```

```css
.crew_box {
  padding: 15px;
}
.crew_box > img {
  max-width: 90%;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <title>About </title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/about.css" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
  </head>

  <body>
     
      </div>
      
        <div class="crew_box">   
          <h5>Our Crew</h5>
          
      
    </div>
      </section>

      <footer>
      </footer>
      <script src="js/about.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

[image: Screenshot from the errors in my console. I don't understand them. When I do the code here the images display, but not in my live server.]

Comment: 403 means Forbidden. Check the response body and headers for a clue as to why the server isn’t allowing the request.  It could be because of something as simple as a missing User-Agent in the request headers.

Comment: You've got a typo: `"${crew.image}"` should be using backticks, not quotes.

Comment: @jmargolisvt The double quotes are for the `src` attribute. The backticks are already in the correct place wrapping all HTML elements.

Answer (score 0):

There maybe a check for `https` from imgur's side, you can get around it by using
[http-server](https://www.npmjs.com/package/http-server) or [ngrok](https://ngrok.com/).

Make sure you install either of the packages globally.

```
npm install -g http-server
```

or

```
npm i -g ngrok
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I am a beginner so I will try to understand what that means:)

Answer (score 0):

You didn't close the `<img/>` tag in your template literal. Whatever caused the `403` is beyond me. Though the `image` properties from the response in your example are different and do work.

```js
const url = "https://api.spacexdata.com/v4/crew";
const resultsContainer = document.querySelector(".crew_box");

async function fetchInfo() {
  try {
    const response = await fetch(url);
    const results = await response.json();

    results.forEach(function (crew) {
      resultsContainer.innerHTML += `
        <div class="crew_box">
          <img src="${crew.image}" />                                    
          <h6>${crew.name}</h6>
          <h6>${crew.agency}</h6>
        </div>`;
    });
  } catch (error) {
    console.log(error);
    resultsContainer.innerHTML = message("error", error);
  }
}

fetchInfo();
```

```css
.crew_box {
  padding: 15px;
}

.crew_box>img {
  max-width: 90%;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8" />
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
  <title>About </title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/about.css" />
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
</head>

<body>

  </div>

  <div class="crew_box">
    <h5>Our Crew</h5>


  </div>
  </section>

  <footer>
  </footer>
  <script src="js/about.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I will test this now!

Answer (score 0):

You might need to make sure to insert the new data, after the image is fully loaded, like so:

```js
const url = "https://api.spacexdata.com/v4/crew";
const resultsContainer = document.querySelector(".crew_box");

async function fetchInfo() {
  try {
    const response = await fetch(url);
    const results = await response.json();

    results.forEach(function (crew) {
      const crewBox = document.createElement('div');
      const crewImg = new Image();
      crewImg.src = crew.image;
      crewBox.classList.add('crew_box');
      crewImg.onload = function() {
        crewBox.prepend(crewImg);
        crewBox.innerHTML += `
          <h6>${crew.name}</h6>
          <h6>${crew.agency}</h6>
        `;
      }
      resultsContainer.appendChild(crewBox);
    });
  } catch (error) {
    console.log(error);
    resultsContainer.innerHTML = message("error", error);
  }
}

fetchInfo();
```

```css
.crew_box {
  padding: 15px;
}
.crew_box > img {
  max-width: 90%;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <title>About </title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/about.css" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
  </head>

  <body>
    <div class="crew_box">   
      <h5>Our Crew</h5>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I'm testing it now.

Answer (score 0):

HTML:

```
<div id="crypto"></div>
```

JS:

```
fetch("urlAddress")
    .then(res => {
        if (!res.ok) {
            throw Error("Something went wrong")
        }
        return res.json()
    })
    .then(data => {
        **document.getElementById("crypto").innerHTML = `
            <img src=${objectName.imageName}>**
          `    
    })
    .catch(err => console.error(err))
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).